# is there any difference in efficiency when using a native method like .join() instead of writting the logic behing it by ourselves?

Tags: javascript, abstraction

If I write by myself the code behind the layer of abstraction of a native method, instead of using that method (which will behind scenes do the same that I write manually), have a good impact on the app performance or speed?

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Compare your custom function vs the native implementation on https://jsperf.com or any other benchmark sites.

Comment: As with many optimisation questions, the answer is - measure it and also, makes sure this is a bottleneck first. If it turns out that you've doubled the speed but it only goes from taking 20ms to 10ms in total, that's a wasted effort, if another code the application takes 2 seconds to run.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd expect a native `.join` to be more performant as it's likely to already be optimised. Maybe outside JS, as well - it might be calling more performant native operation set to deal with strings - something you won't have access to from JS (unless you write it in C++ or something and provide a hook, I suppose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) three significant advantages of using a built-in function instead of implementing it yourself:

(1) Speed - built-in functions generally invoke lower-level code provided by the *browser* (not in Javascript), and said code often runs significantly faster than the same code would in Javascript. Polyfills are slower than native code.

(2) Readability - if another reader of your code sees `['foo', 'bar'].join(' ')`, they'll *immediately* know what it does, and how the `join` method works. On the other hand, if they see something like `doJoin(['foo', 'bar'], ' ')`, where `doJoin` is your own implementation of the same method, they'll have to look up the `doJoin` method to be sure of what's happening there.

(3) Accuracy - what if you make a mistake while writing your implementation, but the mistake is not immediately obvious? That could be a problem. In contrast, the built-in methods almost never have bugs (and, when spotted, usually get fixed).

One could also argue that there's no point spending effort on a solved problem.

Comment: And aside from speed, there is the effort involved. Even assuming you can write a more performant code than a native implementation, the time you spend to do that might be better used to do something else. For example, analysing what, if anything, is a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference in efficiency in some cases. There are some examples in the docs for the library [fast.js](https://github.com/codemix/fast.js/tree/master). To summarize what they say, you don't have to handle all of the cases laid out in the spec so sometimes you can do some things faster that the built in implementations.

I wouldn't take this as a license to make your code harder to read/maintain/reuse based on premature optimization, but yes you may gain some speed with your own implementation of a native method depending on your use case.